# Multiply a random vector by an orthogonal matrix. The result has the same distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

If $X$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with i.i.d. components that are standard normal, and $A$ is an $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix, how do we show $AX$ has the same distribution as $X$?

I kinda know each component of $AX$ is standard normal. This is because orthogonal matrices' each row is of unit norm, and so the $i^{\text{th}}$ component of $AX$, $AX_{i}$ will have the variance equal to $a_{i1}^{2} + \cdots + a_{in}^{2}$ = 1. Also the sum of normal variables is normal so $AX_{i}$ is a standard normal variable.

However, how should I show the components of $AX$ are independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the more general result: if $X \sim N(0, I_n)$ is a multivariate normal vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a fixed matrix (assumed to be invertible/full rank), then $AX \sim N(0, AA^T$).

One way to see this is to do the multivariate change of variable from the standard normal density $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{n/2}} e^{-(1/2) x^T x}$. The density of $AX$ (with Jacobian $A$) is given by
$$
f_{AX}(z) = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{n/2} |\det(A)| } e^{-(1/2) z^T A^{-T} A^{-1} z} = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{n/2} |\mathrm{det}(AA^T)|^{1/2}} e^{-(1/2) z^T (AA^T)^{-1} z} .
$$
(There are also other equivalent ways of defining the multivariate normal distribution.)

Thus, specialising to your case where $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, i.e. $AA^T = I$ and $\det(AA^T) = 1$, it is clear that the density of $Ax$ is the same as the standard normal density. Thus, $Ax \sim N(0, I_n)$.

The fact that the coordinates are independent follows from looking at the density:
$$
f_{Ax}(z) = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{n/2}} e^{-(1/2) \sum_{i=1}^n z_i^2} = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(1/2) z_i^2} .
$$
i.e. the joint density factorises into a product of the $n$ one-dimensional normal densities of its marginals.

Comment: If the covariance matrix is the identity, then they are independent, there is no need to do any more work. This is a special property of the multivariate normal distribution, uncorrelated = independent!

Comment: Yes - and this fact follows from what I said.